# Executes Javascript automatically on extension button click

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a Chrome extension fetching an online JSON containing data about map rotations in a video game. The maps rotates every 4 hours, so the JSON on the host side is updated too when the map changes.

The thing is, (let's say the maps/JSON update at 3pm) when I click on the button of my extension after 3pm, the extension loads the JSON of the previous rotation and not the new JSON. I would like the extension to update the JSON and the DOM every time the user clicks on the button extension. This is my code:

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Splat Rotations",
    "description": "Fetch the current and upcoming Splatoon rotations without SplatNet log in",
    "version": "1.0",

    "icons": {
            "16": "images/icon16.png",
            "19": "images/icon19.png",
            "32": "images/icon32.png",
            "38": "images/icon38.png",
            "48": "images/icon48.png",
            "128": "images/icon128.png"
    },

    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Splat Rotations",
        "default_icon": {
            "16": "images/icon16.png",
            "19": "images/icon19.png",
            "32": "images/icon32.png",
            "38": "images/icon38.png",
            "48": "images/icon48.png",
            "128": "images/icon128.png"
        },
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },

    "permissions": [
        "https://splatoon.ink/"
    ]
}
```

popup.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Splat Rotations</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="popup.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="rotations"></div>
        <footer></footer>
        <script src="popup.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
// Get Splatoon map rotations using the Splatoon.ink API

function retrieveRotations() {

    // Retrieve JSON file
    var AJAX_req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    AJAX_req.open("GET", 'https://splatoon.ink/schedule.json', true);
    AJAX_req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

    AJAX_req.onreadystatechange = function() {

        // Check if splatoon.ink is up and running
        if(AJAX_req.readyState == 4 && AJAX_req.status == 200) {

            // Parse JSON
            var json = JSON.parse(AJAX_req.responseText)
            parseRotations(json);
        }
    }
    AJAX_req.send(null);
}

// Parse acquired data

function parseRotations(data) {


            ////
            //// This is just parsing the JSON and adding divs with the data to the DOM.
            ////
}

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    retrieveRotations();
}, false);
```

I could add a button and a click event listener but this requires from the user to do two actions (click the extension button, then click another refresh button), but I really don't want to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably was a cache problem so I appended the current timestamp to the JSON with an URL parameter so the JSON is never the same.

```
var noCacheJSON = new Date().getTime();
AJAX_req.open("GET", 'https://url.json?c='+noCacheJSON, true);
```

It's finally working as it should!

Answer (score -1):

Have your `popup.js` file include:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    retrieveRotations();
    //Other Actions
}
```

Comment: How is this different than the `window.addEventListener('load')` that is already present?

Comment: Because you don't need to actually have a popup appear to click another box, you can just have it trigger the action without an actual popup.

Comment: Your other option would be: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#event-onClicked

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.  By my understanding, the only possible difference would be: `DOMContentLoaded` -> `popup.css` loaded -> window loaded.  But that doesn't seem to affect the behavior of the ajax call.  Similarly, I don't see how using `browserAction.onClicked` will change anything at all.  It seems to be a caching problem, but that's not my expertise.

Comment: I already tried DOMContentLoaded instead of load and the result is the same.

Answer (score -1):

"I would like the extension to update the JSON and the DOM every time the user clicks on the button extension." You need to use the chrome.browserAction API in a background.js file for detecting clicks on the extension icon. Per the chrome.browserAction [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction), this code looks like:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
   //Execute your content script here...
   chrome.tabs.executeScript({ file: "popup.js" }); 
});
```

For further reference, check out Google's chrome extension [examples](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples). The example titled, "A browser action which changes its icon when clicked" will also show how to handle clicking the extension icon.

Comment: I can't use chrome.browserAction.onClicked if the extension has a popup unfortunately.